# length of ’dimnames’ [1] not equal to array extent

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot the composition for a list of DNA sequences in fasta file format. I have the following code but it is generating an error and I cant seem to figure out there the issue lies.

```
    library(ggplot2)
    library(reshape2)
    library(gridExtra)
    library(seqinr)

    #read sequence from file
    seqs <- read.fasta("seqs.fasta")

    total_seqs <- length(seqs)
    proportion <- function(x,t=sum(x)){ x/t}
    normalize <- function(x,m=mean(x,...),s=sd(x,...),...){(x-m)/s}

    mylist <- list()
    for (i in 1:total_seqs){
      mylist[[i]] <- (count(seqs[[i]],1))
    }

    composition.dta <- data.frame(do.call("rbind",mylist))

    #get the propotions
    composition.dta.prop <- t(data.frame(apply(composition.dta,1,proportion)))

    #melt this dataframe
    composition.dta.prop.m <- melt(composition.dta.prop,value.name="proportion")

    #do the plot
    composition.plot <- ggplot(composition.dta.prop.m,aes(Var2,proportion)) +
      geom_point() +
      geom_boxplot() +
      theme_classic()

grid.arrange(composition.plot)
```

This is resulting in this error:

```
## Error in ‘rownames<-‘(‘*tmp*‘, value = c("1.5", "1.9", "1.33",
"1.21", : length of ’dimnames’ [1] not equal to array extent
## Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object ’seqs’ not found
## Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object ’total_seqs’ not
found
```

Any ideas where what would result in this?

Thank you.

sample DNA dataset is here http://pastebin.com/vdygaqPv

Comment: Why do you use `grid.arrange` and not simply `print(composition.plot)`?

Comment: because I plan to add another plot and print them on a grid for a latex /knitr document. But there is not other reason why I can use print.

Comment: OK. Since this isn't reproducible without data, I have nothing else to add.

Comment: Its not fair to simply down vote the question. I can upload data somewhere. I thought there is something wrong with the code.

Comment: see above list of sample sequences. http://pastebin.com/vdygaqPv

Comment: For what it's worth, your script 'works for me' as written. Also FWIW I'd have used the [Biostrings](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Biostrings.html) package from Bioconductor; `library(Biostrings); dna = readDNAStringSet("seqs.fasta"); alphabetFrequency(dna, baseOnly=TRUE, as.prob=TRUE)` to get to the nucleotide frequencies.

Comment: Thank you @morgan  for suggesting  Biostrings. The plot works when I use the Bioconductor approach which suggests there is something not right with my loop. ( i think).  :( Any way am very glad for the alternative suggestion.